# move next by pressing enter key not working in date field of html

Tags: html, jquery, google-chrome

move next by pressing enter key not working in date field of html after the chrome version updated my google chrome Version is 83.0.4103.61 now when i press enter it shows me date picker instead of move to other field

```js
$(document).on('keypress','#from_date',function(e){
//alert("in");
e.preventDefault();
  if(e.which == 13){
     $('#to_date').focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" class="form-control customInp" name="from_date" value="2020-05-20" id="from_date">
<input type="date" class="form-control customInp" name="to_date" value="" id="to_date">
```

Comment: I try to press enter in first field, and move to next. Version : 81.0.4044.138

Comment: it's working in my previous version of chrome before update but not working in updated version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override this new behavior of opening the date picker on enter with a preventDefault on the enter keydown.

```js
function preventDatePickerOnEnter(evt) {
  if (evt.which === 13) { // enter key
    console.log('prevented date picker on enter')
    evt.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="date" onkeydown="preventDatePickerOnEnter(event)">
```

Comment: i just need to change **keypress** with **keydown**

Answer (score 0):

The smartypants at Google managed to screw up something in their new datepicker that has worked since INPUT fields were added to HTML in the 1990s...the behavior of the ENTER key. In v82 and before, if you hit ENTER while typing a date in an  the normal form experience (like any other INPUT) would be to submit the form. Some settings may interpret ENTER to move to the next field (much like the TAB key).

Beginning with Chrome v83, the ENTER key merely opens the date-picker UI. So, there is no native way to submit the form if the user is within the date field. This would be fine if this had been the paradigm on the web previously, but this upends 20+ years of web development and UX. Nice job dudes.

For more info, see: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/05/nic83 or https://blog.chromium.org/2020/03/updates-to-form-controls-and-focus.html

To answer OP's question: YES, INPUT TYPE="date" has changed significantly in v83, so it is NOT unique to you.

Comment: I know the behaviour of date field is change in chrome 83+ but i want solution how to move next from date field using enter key.